# rake db:migrate problems with using paperclip

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, image-uploading, dbmigrate

I installed paperclip 2.7 using gem install. I did rails generate paperclip user photo. and then tried migrate the db. But it gave me an error.
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: photo_file_name: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "photo_file_name" varchar(255)

I read somewhere that I should do delete the development.rb and then do db:create and them migrate again. But that didn't work either. When I did db:create it said already exists. 
So...I ended up reverting back to my old commit hoping to start again. But when I do db:reset. it tell me i have two migrations left. These two migrations are from rails generate paperclip user photo. 
What do I do now? How am I to get this to work?

Comment: You have already that column on that table. You can try deleting it first, or changing it. Take a look at the table schema. Review your migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't have any data that is important and needs to be saved you can simply drop the db and migrate it all the way back up:

rake db:drop

rake db:create

rake db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

Run a migration removing `photo_file_name`, thus:

```
def change
  change_table :users do |t|
    t.remove :photo_file_name
  end
end
```

And start again.